# Function call, apply and bind are not setting context as expected

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a class that stores a function on instantiation in a property. I then run that function from a method in that class. The code is called via two other classes.

Here is a very stripped down version of what it looks like:

```
//file: A.js
class A {
  constructor(fn) {
    this.fn = fn;
  }
  run() {
    console.log(`A.run: typeof this.init: ${typeof this.init}`);
    console.log(`A.run: typeof this.go: ${typeof this.go}`);
    console.log(`A.run: typeof this.run: ${typeof this.run}`);
    
    const arg1 = 'test1';
    const arg2 = 'test2';
    this.fn(arg1, arg2);
  }
}

module.exports = A;
```

Initially run is called from within another class:

```
//file: B.js
const A = require('./A');
class B {
  constructor() {}
  go() {
    console.log(`B.go: typeof this.init: ${typeof this.init}`);
    console.log(`B.go: typeof this.go: ${typeof this.go}`);
    console.log(`B.go: typeof this.run: ${typeof this.run}`);
    
    const fn = function() {
      console.log(`fn: typeof this.init: ${typeof this.init}`);
      console.log(`fn: typeof this.go: ${typeof this.go}`);
      console.log(`fn: typeof this.run: ${typeof this.run}`);
    }
    
    const a = new A(fn);
    a.run();
  }
}

module.exports = B;
```

And that is called from another class, from inside an arrow function:

```
// file: C.js
const B = require('./B');
class C {
  constructor() {}
  init() {
    console.log(`C.init: typeof this.init: ${typeof this.init}`);
    console.log(`C.init: typeof this.go: ${typeof this.go}`);
    console.log(`C.init: typeof this.run: ${typeof this.run}`);
    
    const arrayOfB = [];
    arrayOfB.push(new B());
    arrayOfB.map(b => b.go());
  }
}
```

The arrayOfA is created by pushing new objects into an array.

The function fn needs to be able to call itself, so it needs to have the run method in the context.

Here is the output from the above code:

```
start test
C.init: typeof this.init: function
C.init: typeof this.go: undefined
C init: typeof this.run: undefined
B.go: typeof this.init: undefined
B.go: typeof this.go: function
B.go: typeof this.run: undefined
A.run: typeof this.init: undefined
A.run: typeof this.go: undefined
A.run: typeof this.run: function
fn:typeof this.init: undefined
fn.typeof this.go: undefined
fn.typeof this.run: function
done test
```

So the minimal example works. I’ve dropped it right into my real code next to the existing code, and it works. I can’t figure out why the existing code doesn’t work, even though it’s basically the same thing happening.

In the actual implementation there are also a bunch of other properties that hold data which it needs to see. It’s too complicated to share here, but it’s essentially the very same structure.

In the real code:

When I debug log the context inside run method, everything is there as expected.

When I debug log the context inside fn, the context has not been set. The run method is undefined.

I have tried apply and bind, same result.

Could calling a.run() from in arrow function result in the context setting failing?

This was previously working, but after a refactor, moving various classes around etc, the context no longer gets set correctly.

What could cause the context to not be set as expected?

Comment: Please share how you call and use this class? Also `arg1, arg2` have not been defined in the `run` method.

Comment: The update doesn't show how `arrayOfA` is made.

Comment: "*This was previously working, but after a refactor, the context no longer gets set correctly.*" - please post both the working and the non-working code. Especially including the `fn` whose context is no longer what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and help. I have added requested additional info about how the array is created and how run is called.

Comment: I have updated the minimal example to more closely look like the real implementation. I’m still stuck, any ideas?